# AWS amplify full stack demo build error at geo/lib-esm/util.js:

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

was playing around going through this AWS amplify tutorial (auth,S3, graphql setup)

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-five/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-four

all working locally but fails CI (and local npm run build) due to the following error... any ideas boys and girls?

```
node_modules/@aws-amplify/geo/lib-esm/util.js: symbol.charCodeAt is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

running these versions :

```
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.0.0",
"aws-amplify": "^5.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade your aws-amplify to 3.4.1
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/10773

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by

1. removing node_modules, yarn.lock and package-lock.json
2. rerun `yarn build`